# UNION tables with wildcard in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, wildcard

I have over 40 tables I want to append in BigQuery using standard SQL. I have already formatted them to have the exact same schema. When I try to use the '*' wildcard at the end of table name in my FROM clause, I get the following error:

Syntax error: Expected end of input but got "*" at [95:48]

I ended up manually doing a UNION DISTINCT on all my tables. Is this the best way to do this? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

```
CREATE TABLE capstone-320521.Trips.Divvy_Trips_All AS 
SELECT * FROM capstone-320521.Trips.Divvy_Trips_*;



--JOIN all 2020-21 trips data
CREATE TABLE capstone-320521.Trips.Divvy_Trips_Raw_2020_2021 AS 
SELECT * FROM capstone-320521.Trips.Divvy_Trips_2020_04  
UNION DISTINCT 
SELECT * FROM capstone-320521.Trips.Divvy_Trips_2020_05  
UNION DISTINCT 
SELECT * FROM capstone-320521.Trips.Divvy_Trips_2020_06 
UNION DISTINCT
```

Comment: Without changing the schema (to avoid N tables and instead have one), this is about all you can do.  Note: A table name in the FROM clause can not be a pattern.  You could use a kind of VIEW (or common table expressions, etc), instead of creating a base table.  That doesn't change the basic problem.

Comment: ticks are `a must` when you have `*` in table reference as a wild card - which you do have here. see how you should use it in my answer

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much! I thought I already tried it but I see now that it indeed works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Syntax error: Expected end of input but got "*"

I think the problem is in missing ticks around the table references. Try below

```
CREATE TABLE `capstone-320521.Trips.Divvy_Trips_All` AS 
SELECT * FROM `capstone-320521.Trips.Divvy_Trips_*`
```

Note: The wildcard table name contains the special character (*), which means that you must enclose the wildcard table name in backtick (`) characters. See more at [Enclose table names with wildcards in backticks](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/wildcard-table-reference#enclose_table_names_with_wildcards_in_backticks)

Answer (score 0):

I am unaware of any such `UNION DISTINCT` syntax.  If your intention is to do a union of the 3 tables and remove any duplicate records in the process, then just using `UNION` should suffice:

```sql
CREATE TABLE capstone-320521.Trips.Divvy_Trips_Raw_2020_2021 AS
SELECT * FROM capstone-320521.Trips.Divvy_Trips_2020_04
UNION
SELECT * FROM capstone-320521.Trips.Divvy_Trips_2020_05
UNION
SELECT * FROM capstone-320521.Trips.Divvy_Trips_2020_06;
```

Note that in general it is bad practice to use `SELECT *` with union queries.  The reason has to do with that a union between two (or more) tables is generally only valid if the two queries involved have the number *and* types of columns.  Using `SELECT *` obfuscates what columns are actually being selected, and so it is preferable to always explicitly list out the columns.